# Emacs 26.3 scrollbar refuses to move up if not moved up immediately

Tags: emacs, emacs26

On Fedora Release 31.  Using Xming on Windows 7 as X server.  **EDIT: also Emacs 24.3 running on RHEL7 with MobaXterm 12.2 4204, whether in -Q mode or not**

The scrollbar I'm seeing is a medium-dark rectangle (the scrollbar "elevator") with rounded left-hand corners and square right-hand corners, in a light-gray vertical area (the scrollbar "track").  When I mouse over the rectangle it switches to dark gray.

When I click it, it turns blue.  After about 1/2 second, if not moved, it narrows about 2 pixels on the right **[EDIT: on the 24.3/RHEL7/MobaXterm setup, narrows on both sides]**, and refuses to move.  Moving the mouse will sometimes get one scroll of the window contents, and sometimes not.

If I click it and move it slightly in that 1/2 second, it will move, and continue to be movable even if I hold still for a while.  But I have to move it substantially (at least half its height, it seems, in a 2000 line file) or it will then freeze at the 1/2 second mark.

Here's my current `.emacs` file:

```
(defun switch-to-next-buffer-frank ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer)))

(defun switch-to-prev-window ()
  (interactive)
  (other-window -1))

(defun scroll-one-line-up (&optional arg)
  "Scroll the selected window up (forward in the text) one line (or N lines)."
  (interactive "p")
  (scroll-up (or arg 1)))

(defun scroll-one-line-down (&optional arg)
  "Scroll the selected window down (backward in the text) one line (or N)."
  (interactive "p")
  (scroll-down (or arg 1)))

(global-set-key [(control ?z)]                'scroll-one-line-up)
(global-set-key [(meta ?z)]                   'scroll-one-line-down)
(global-set-key [(meta ?g)]                   'goto-line)
(global-set-key [(control ?x)(k)]             'kill-this-buffer)
(global-set-key [(control meta ?l)]           'switch-to-next-buffer)
(global-set-key [(control shift meta ?l)]     'switch-to-prev-buffer)
(global-set-key [(control tab)]               'other-window)
(global-set-key [(control shift iso-lefttab)] 'switch-to-prev-window)

(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")

(setq scroll-bar-mode 'left)
(setq scroll-bar-adjust-thumb-portion nil)





(setq gutter-buffers-tab-visible-p nil)
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
(setq mouse-yank-at-point t)
(setq inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(delete-selection-mode 1)
;(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
;(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
;(setq initial-scratch-message nil)



;(delete-selection-mode 1)
;
;(defun ask-user-about-supersession-threat (fn)
;  "blatantly ignore files that changed on disk"
;  )





(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 '(ansi-color-names-vector
   ["#3F3F3F" "#CC9393" "#7F9F7F" "#F0DFAF" "#8CD0D3" "#DC8CC3" "#93E0E3" "#DCDCCC"])
 '(background-color "#000000")
 '(background-mode dark)
 '(company-quickhelp-color-background "#4F4F4F")
 '(company-quickhelp-color-foreground "#DCDCCC")
 '(cursor-color "#ffffff")
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (manoj-dark)))
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("54f2d1fcc9bcadedd50398697618f7c34aceb9966a6cbaa99829eb64c0c1f3ca" "4138944fbed88c047c9973f68908b36b4153646a045648a22083bd622d1e636d" "8885761700542f5d0ea63436874bf3f9e279211707d4b1ca9ed6f53522f21934" "59e82a683db7129c0142b4b5a35dbbeaf8e01a4b81588f8c163bd255b76f4d21" default)))
 '(fci-rule-color "#383838")
 '(font-use-system-font t)
 '(foreground-color "#00ff00")
 '(gutter-buffers-tab-visible-p nil t)
 '(indent-tabs-mode nil)
 '(nrepl-message-colors
   (quote
    ("#CC9393" "#DFAF8F" "#F0DFAF" "#7F9F7F" "#BFEBBF" "#93E0E3" "#94BFF3" "#DC8CC3")))
 '(pdf-view-midnight-colors (quote ("#DCDCCC" . "#383838")))
 '(query-user-mail-address nil)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil)
 '(user-mail-address "fsheeran@gmail.com")
 '(vc-annotate-background "#2B2B2B")
 '(vc-annotate-color-map
   (quote
    ((20 . "#BC8383")
     (40 . "#CC9393")
     (60 . "#DFAF8F")
     (80 . "#D0BF8F")
     (100 . "#E0CF9F")
     (120 . "#F0DFAF")
     (140 . "#5F7F5F")
     (160 . "#7F9F7F")
     (180 . "#8FB28F")
     (200 . "#9FC59F")
     (220 . "#AFD8AF")
     (240 . "#BFEBBF")
     (260 . "#93E0E3")
     (280 . "#6CA0A3")
     (300 . "#7CB8BB")
     (320 . "#8CD0D3")
     (340 . "#94BFF3")
     (360 . "#DC8CC3"))))
 '(vc-annotate-very-old-color "#DC8CC3"))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:foreground "#00ff00" :background "#000000" :size "10pt" :family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foundry "PfEd" :slant normal :weight normal :height 144 :width normal))))
 '(font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground "#00ccff"))))
 '(font-lock-comment-delimiter-face ((t (:foreground "#ffff00" :slant normal))))
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "#ffff00" :slant normal))))
 '(font-lock-constant-face ((t (:foreground "#00ff99" :weight normal))))
 '(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "#00ff00" :weight normal :height 1.0))))
 '(font-lock-preprocessor-face ((t (:foreground "#ff4040"))))
 '(font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground "#00ffee"))))
 '(font-lock-type-face ((t (:foreground "#33ccff"))))
 '(font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground "#66ff00"))))
 '(italic ((t nil)))
 '(mode-line ((t (:background "#445555" :foreground "#ffffff" :box (:line-width 2 :color "#445555") :height 1.0))))
 '(mode-line-buffer-id ((t (:background "#445555" :foreground "#55ff55" :weight normal :height 1.0))))
 '(mode-line-emphasis ((t (:weight normal))))
 '(mode-line-highlight ((t (:box (:line-width 2 :color "#445555")))))
 '(mode-line-inactive ((t (:background "#445555" :foreground "#ffffff" :box (:line-width 2 :color "#445555") :weight normal :height 1.0))))
 '(scroll-bar ((t (:background "#334444" :foreground "#ddffff")))))
```

Here's a screenshot: of emacs -Q 24.3/RHEL7/MobaXterm:[image]

Then here is the same window after I've held the top scrollbar about 1 second without moving after clicking down:[image]

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you run Emacs with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: Consider adding screenshots to the question.  It might make it a little easier to understand the issue.

Comment: Yes, emacs -Q <filename> has the same inability to scroll, and the weird thing of the elevator narrowing a couple pixels at the same time it stops being able to scroll.

Comment: jpg won't help.  a movie might help but why not just read what I wrote and picture it in your head?  Much less bandwidth :-D

Comment: I still think a screenshot might help (other users of similar systems would immediately be able to see if the "narrowing" looked normal or not, for instance).  I don't have scroll bars like that on my system, so I can't trivially picture it in my head.

Comment: As you've said things are the same under `emacs -Q` you can remove everything about your config file from the question.  It's complicating things for no reason.  In place of that simply say you're running `emacs -Q` (and also the `M-x emacs-version` details, which you can copy from the `*Messages*` buffer).

Comment: Thanks, added screenshots of narrowed unmoving scrollbar vs. normal.  Since I've discovered the same "bug" on two different major releases of emacs, on two different OSes, with two different Xservers, I'm now thinking it's just some "feature" I don't understand.  (And if I could figure out the name of this feature perhaps I could turn it off.)  BTW I'm not wed to any particular scrollbar look/feel, so if you use another one I'd be happy to try something else.